# Using loop to plot multiple results

Tags: matlab

I want to plot the result for the raw and window: 10 50 100 all in one plot using a for loop [This the plot i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAixM.png)

[image]
below is my code

```
%Read data in
    data = csvread('z_flip_data_60BPM.csv');

    %Assign columns from csv
    z_raw = data(:,2); %Raw signal from data collection
    time = data(:,1)/1000; %time converted to seconds

    plot(time,z_raw);
    hold on
    %Change window size as required
    window = [10 50 100]; 

    %sanity check to avoid improper window size settings
    if window>length(z_raw)
        return;
    end

    %Indexing for the filtered array
    j = 1;

    %Moving average window filter + basic plot
    for i = window+1:(length(z_raw))
        filtered_z(j) = mean(z_raw(i-window:i));
        j = j+1;

        plot(filtered_z);
        hold on
    end

    hold off
```

Comment: You are not specifying the X-axes positions. I suspect its all plotted, all in that bunch in the beggining, where it looks clogged.

Comment: Ander is right. Your 3 `filtered_z` vectors have a different number of points than the raw signal. For each of your windowed signal you need to rebuild an adequate time vector and use it for the plot.