# Plot multiple results using for loop

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot raw and window 10, 50 and 100 all in one graph. I get:

Error using plot

Vectors must be the same length.

Error in moving_avg_filter (line 34)

plot(t,filtered_z)

When I ran the code with only plot(filtered_z). In the workspace it showed that filtered_z is 1x2296 so I tried to set t the same. However, when I ran it using plot(t,filtered_z) it didn't work and the values in the workspace changed to this:
[workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2JJT.png)

Also, I tried placing the plot outside the for loop and it worked, but it will only give the last loop. So, how can I fix this?

Below is my code.

```
clear
clc
%You will need to add the logic for plotting all window 
%sizes and FFT as instructed in the lab document

%Read data in
data = csvread('z_flip_data_60BPM.csv');

%Assign columns from csv
z_raw = data(:,2); %Raw signal from data collection
time = data(:,1)/1000; %time converted to seconds

plot(time,z_raw,'r');
hold on
%Change window size as required
window = [10 50 100]; 

%sanity check to avoid improper window size settings
if window>length(z_raw)
    return;
end


%Indexing for the filtered array
j = 1;
t = time(1:2296,1);

%Moving average window filter + basic plot
for i = window+1:(length(z_raw))
    filtered_z(j) = mean(z_raw(i-window:i));
    j = j+1;
    plot(t,filtered_z)
hold on

end

hold off
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using loop to plot multiple results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61637403/using-loop-to-plot-multiple-results)

Comment: in which way is this question different from your [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61637403/using-loop-to-plot-multiple-results)?